# vue.js accessing this.$route.params in mounted functions

Tags: vue.js, routes

I'm trying to filter table of movies by director ID. The structure of a movie is:

```
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "They All Lie",
          releaseYear: 1989,
          director: {
            id: 18,
            firstName: "Darci",
            lastName: "Overill",
            nationality: "China",
            birthdate: "07/13/1973",
          },
        },
```

I want to filter the table using the `$route.params.id`. I have the following code:

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      directorId: this.$route.params.id,
      director: {},
      movies: [],
    };
  },
  mounted: function () {
     this.getDirector();
    this.getMovies();

  },
  methods: {
    getMovies: function () {
      let url = "http://localhost:8080/movies/movies";
      axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        this.movies = response.data;
      });
    },
    getDirector: function () {
      let url = "http://localhost:8080/movies/directors/" + this.directorId;
      axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        this.director = response.data;
      });
    },
  },
  computed: {
    filteredMovies: function () {
      var v = this.$route.params.id;
      alert(v);
      return this.movies.filter(movie => movie.director.id === v);
    },
  }
  
};
</script>
```

I'm trying to access `this.$route.params.id` in the `filteredMovies` function. It works in the .alert function **but I can't get the** `return this.movies.filter(movie => movie.director.id === v);` to work. The filtering doesn't work. Any ideas please?

Comment: if `movie.director.id` is a number then you need to parse it and check like this `movie.director.id === parseInt(v)`

Comment: Also consider creating variables in the data object data: function () {
    return { v:null } } because the variables that have been created outside of this block are not reactive.

Comment: Many thanks! Parsing the id was the way to go!

Comment: Hey!Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more elegant solution for parsing the router param id check tis out:

index.js(router file)

```
{
    path: '/directors/:id',
    name: 'Directors',
    component: myComponentName,
    props: (route) => {
      const id = Number.parseInt(route.params.id);
      return { id }
    }
  }
```

**Component.vue**

```
 props: {
    id: {
      required: true,
      type: Number,
    }
```

With the above implementation you can remove the parsing in the component and also instead of doing this:

```
this.$route.params.id;
```

Now you can do:

```
this.id
```

And you have the parsed id with best practises ;)

Cheers